# function gets stuck / freezes in the return statement

Tags: android, arraylist, return, freeze

I have a function which is supposed to return an object of arraylists but for some reason it gets stuck in the return statement. Everything before the return statement is working. I had an error where the ArrayLists only contained a single value which makes the function work, but of course returns the wrong data.

```
package com.burninglobster.TP;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Chart2Activity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Object graphdata[] = graphsetup();
            Log.d("This message is NOT shown", "");

    List<Double> distances = (List<Double>) graphdata[0];
    List<Double> accall = (List<Double>) graphdata[1];
    List<Double> accdir = (List<Double>) graphdata[2];
    List<Double> accdist = (List<Double>) graphdata[3];
    List<Double> meandir = (List<Double>) graphdata[4];
    List<Double> meandist = (List<Double>) graphdata[5];
    linegraph lgraph = new linegraph();

    setContentView(R.layout.splot);

    LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splot2);
    layout1.addView(lgraph.getView1(this, distances, accall));

    LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splot3);
    layout2.addView(lgraph.getView2(this, distances, accdir, meandir));

    LinearLayout layout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splot4);
    layout3.addView(lgraph.getView2(this, distances, accdist, meandist));
}


public Object[] graphsetup() {

    SharedPreferences rprefs;
    rprefs = getSharedPreferences("com.burninglobster.TP.tprefs",
            Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    double setdist = rprefs.getFloat("setdist", 0);

    String[] sourcesarray = rprefs.getString("sourcesarray", "Standarddef")
            .split(",");
    String setdisc = sourcesarray[rprefs.getInt("spindiscpos", 0)];
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(Chart2Activity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String graphquery = "SELECT " + DBHelper.SHOOTER + "," + DBHelper.WDIR
            + "," + DBHelper.WSTR + "," + DBHelper.SMOD + ","
            + DBHelper.DIST + "," + DBHelper.R_DIST + ","
            + DBHelper.OS_DIST + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE + " WHERE "
            + DBHelper.SHOOTER + "='" + setdisc + "'" + " ORDER BY "
            + DBHelper.DIST;
    Cursor graphcursor = db.rawQuery(graphquery, null);
    int rows = graphcursor.getCount();

    int ishooter = graphcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SHOOTER);
    int iwdir = graphcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.WDIR);
    int iwstr = graphcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.WSTR);
    int ismod = graphcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SMOD);
    int idist = graphcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DIST);
    int irdist = graphcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.R_DIST);
    int iosdist = graphcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.OS_DIST);

    List<Double> accall = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> accdir = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> meandir = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> accdist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> meandist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> accdirtemp = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> accdisttemp = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> distances = new ArrayList<Double>();

    double dalla = 0;
    double ddira = 0;
    double ddista = 0;
    double ddirm = 0;
    double ddistm = 0;
    double currentdist = 0;

    graphcursor.moveToFirst();
    if (rows > 0) {
        currentdist = graphcursor.getDouble(idist);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                    // REMOVED ERROR CAUSING SINGLE VALUE IN ARRAYLISTS:
                    // currentdist=graphcursor.getDouble(idist);
        if (graphcursor.getDouble(idist) < (currentdist + 5)) {

            accdirtemp.add(graphcursor.getDouble(irdist));
            accdisttemp.add(graphcursor.getDouble(iosdist));

        } else {

            for (int u = 0; u < accdirtemp.size(); u++) {

                ddira += Math.pow(accdirtemp.get(u), 2);
                ddista += Math.pow(accdisttemp.get(u), 2);
                dalla += Math.pow(accdirtemp.get(u), 2)
                        + Math.pow(accdisttemp.get(u), 2);
                ddirm += accdirtemp.get(u);
                ddistm += accdisttemp.get(u);

            }

            accall.add(Math.sqrt(dalla / accdirtemp.size()));
                    Double.toString(Math.sqrt(dalla / accdirtemp.size())));
            accdir.add(Math.sqrt(ddira / accdirtemp.size()));
            accdist.add(Math.sqrt(ddista / accdirtemp.size()));
            meandir.add(ddirm / accdirtemp.size());
            meandist.add(ddistm / accdirtemp.size());
            distances.add(currentdist);
            dalla = 0;
            ddira = 0;
            ddirm = 0;
            ddista = 0;
            ddistm = 0;

            currentdist = graphcursor.getDouble(idist) + 5;
            accdirtemp.clear();
            accdisttemp.clear();
            accdirtemp.add(graphcursor.getDouble(irdist));
            accdisttemp.add(graphcursor.getDouble(iosdist));

        }

        graphcursor.moveToNext();
    }

    for (int u = 0; u < accdirtemp.size(); u++) {

        ddira += Math.pow(accdirtemp.get(u), 2);
        ddista += Math.pow(accdisttemp.get(u), 2);
        dalla += Math.pow(accdirtemp.get(u), 2)
                + Math.pow(accdisttemp.get(u), 2);
        ddirm += accdirtemp.get(u);
        ddistm += accdisttemp.get(u);

    }

    accall.add(Math.sqrt(dalla / accdirtemp.size()));
    accdir.add(Math.sqrt(ddira / accdirtemp.size()));
    accdist.add(Math.sqrt(ddista / accdirtemp.size()));
    meandir.add(ddirm / accdirtemp.size());
    meandist.add(ddistm / accdirtemp.size());
    distances.add(currentdist);

    db.close();
    dbHelper.close();

            Log.d("This message", " is shown");
    return new Object[] { distances, accall, accdir, accdist, meandir,
            meandist };

}

}
```

I have a similar function that works just fine and I can't see the difference:

```
package com.burninglobster.TP;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ChartActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Object plotdata[] = plotsetup();
            Log.d("This message", " is also shown");

    List<Double> rd1 = (List<Double>) plotdata[0];
    List<Double> osd1 = (List<Double>) plotdata[1];
    List<Double> rd2 = (List<Double>) plotdata[2];
    List<Double> osd2 = (List<Double>) plotdata[3];
    List<Double> rd3 = (List<Double>) plotdata[4];
    List<Double> osd3 = (List<Double>) plotdata[5];
    scatterplot plot = new scatterplot();
    setContentView(R.layout.tplot);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    layout.addView(plot.getView(this, rd1, osd1, rd2, osd2, rd3, osd3));
}

public Object[] plotsetup() {

    SharedPreferences rprefs;
    rprefs = getSharedPreferences("com.burninglobster.TP.tprefs",
            Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    double setdist = rprefs.getFloat("setdist", 0);
    String[] sourcesarray = rprefs.getString("sourcesarray", "Standarddef")
            .split(",");
    String setdisc = sourcesarray[rprefs.getInt("spindiscpos", 0)];

    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(ChartActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String plotquery = "SELECT " + DBHelper.SHOOTER + "," + DBHelper.WDIR
            + "," + DBHelper.WSTR + "," + DBHelper.SMOD + ","
            + DBHelper.DIST + "," + DBHelper.R_DIST + ","
            + DBHelper.OS_DIST + " FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE;
    Cursor plotcursor = db.rawQuery(plotquery, null);
    int ishooter = plotcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SHOOTER);
    int iwdir = plotcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.WDIR);
    int iwstr = plotcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.WSTR);
    int ismod = plotcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SMOD);
    int idist = plotcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DIST);
    int irdist = plotcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.R_DIST);
    int iosdist = plotcursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.OS_DIST);

    int rows = plotcursor.getCount();

    List<Double> rd1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> osd1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> rd2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> osd2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> rd3 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> osd3 = new ArrayList<Double>();

    plotcursor.moveToFirst();
    int disccount = 0;
    int array1 = 0;
    int array2 = 0;
    int array3 = 0;
    double cursordist;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (plotcursor.getString(0).equals(setdisc)) {
            cursordist = plotcursor.getDouble(idist);
            if (cursordist > (setdist - 5) && cursordist < (setdist + 5)) {
                rd1.add(plotcursor.getDouble(irdist));
                osd1.add(plotcursor.getDouble(iosdist));
                array1++;
            } else if (cursordist > (setdist)
                    && cursordist < (setdist + 10)) {
                rd2.add(plotcursor.getDouble(irdist));
                osd2.add(plotcursor.getDouble(iosdist));
                array2++;
            } else if (cursordist > (setdist - 10)
                    && cursordist < (setdist)) {
                rd3.add(plotcursor.getDouble(irdist));
                osd3.add(plotcursor.getDouble(iosdist));
                array3++;
            }
            disccount++;
        }
        plotcursor.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    dbHelper.close();

            Log.d("This message", " is shown");
    return new Object[] { rd1, osd1, rd2, osd2, rd3, osd3 };
}
}
```

I added a 'Log.d' just before the return statement and then another just after the function call in the activity and only the first one is shown. It freezes for ½-1 minute and then shows the dialogue to wait or kill. I don't know how to get more info on the problem. Suggestions?

Comment: I just realised, that I forgot to close the db and dbHelper, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the problem is, and you will have to explain "stuck in the return statement".  Code does not simply get "stuck".

But you will help yourself a lot of you break the problem up.

For example, if you created a class and handled instances of the class rather than untyped arrays of objects, your code would be much easier to write, much easier to debug and much easier to maintain.  Doing so will also enable the compiler to catch a lot of errors before you need to ask for help :)

Whenever you are tempted to use 'Object', you should stop and question yourself.  Of course, there are times when Object is useful and times when you have no choice but they are exceptional and should only be done for good reason - not because you haven't taken the time to think of a correct solution.

You should also choose better names for your variables and use proper Java naming conventions.  Here, I've named the object Thing because your code does not give proper clues as to what dalla, ddira, ddista etc are and how the relate to each other, either in comments or code (which is a bad thing - this code might only ever be seen by you but when you come back in a year, you will wish that you'd done these things).

For example:

```
class Thing{

    double dalla = 0;
    double ddira = 0;
    double ddista = 0;
    double ddirm = 0;
    double ddistm = 0;
    double currentdist = 0;

}
```

Then, in your loops or methods or whatever,

```
ArrayList<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();

...

Thing thing = new Thing();
for (int u = 0; u < accdirtemp.size(); u++) {

    thing.ddira += Math.pow(accdirtemp.get(u), 2);
    thing.ddista += Math.pow(accdisttemp.get(u), 2);
    thing.dalla += Math.pow(accdirtemp.get(u), 2)
            + Math.pow(accdisttemp.get(u), 2);
    thing.ddirm += accdirtemp.get(u);
    thing.ddistm += accdisttemp.get(u);
}

things.add(thing);

...
```

And so on.  Take the time now to refactor your code before it becomes even more of a nightmare to read.

Comment: Very good advise. I know it is important and I have actually improved on my coding sanitation, but I was hoping to smooth out this "bump" and then do a bit of cleaning. 

I added a 'Log.d' just before the return statement and then another just after the function call in the activity and only the first one is shown. It freezes for ½-1 minute and then shows the dialogue to wait or kill. I don't know how to get more info on the problem. Suggestions?

Comment: Why smooth out the bump if you plan to refactor it?  Sounds like double work to me.  It won't take you long and I promise you will feel more satisfied afterwards.  Your coding going forward will then speed up considerably.

Comment: OK, so I'm feeling quite stupid for posting this and wasting coders' time!! My problem was to be found elsewhere. The real problem was, that I was using `Log.d` wrong. If the text string is empty, it seems that it doesn't get sent to the log: 
`Log.d("This return","something")` ; `Log.d("This returns nothing","")` :S
[tag:Log.d]

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm feeling quite stupid for posting this and wasting coders' time!!

My problem was to be found elsewhere. The real problem was, that I was using Log.d wrong. If the text string is empty, it seems that it doesn't get sent to the log: 
`Log.d("This return","something")` ; `Log.d("This returns nothing","")` :S [log.d](/questions/tagged/log.d)